# How to assess relationship between two multiple-choice questions from a suvey?

Tags: survey

I have a survey consisting of number of questions, two of which are multiple-choice questions, with about 10 possible answers each. Can you suggest any concise method of assesing relationship between them?

Toy example:

1. What kind of music you listen to? *(choose as many as you wish)*

a) Rock

b) Pop

c) Dance

...

2. How you spend your free time? *(choose as many as you wish)*

a) Watching TV

b) Reading books

c) Playing computer games

...

Question: are free-time activities related to preferred type of music?

For now, I translate each of them to multiple yes/no questions (one for each possible answer) and use chi-squared test (with Holm's p-value correction) for each pair (is listening to Rock related to watching TV, is listening to Rock related to reading books, and so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were willing to ignore the fact that some people will choose more answers than others, then you could use a log-linear model of the contingency table of the two variables.  That's probably not a good choice, unless very few people chose more than one answer on each.

What I would do is first examine each answer and try to see patterns of combinations of answers.  You could do this informally in a couple ways, or you could try a cluster analysis.  Then you could use that to classify each person into one answer on each question.  Then things become much simpler, and maybe more informative as well.

Comment: Your idea of log-linear model made me think about MDS (Multidimensional Scaling). Maybe I could count distance between each answer form question 1 and each answer from question 2 (like number of people chosing only one answer from given pair) and apply MDS to get a map of answers?

Comment: You could do MDS.  That might get you something interesting.

Comment: I tried. It looks very promising :) Gives more-or-less similar results to my previous chi-squared approach, but much more concisely. Thanks for inspiration. One more (meta-)question: what I do now? Accept you answer or post my own an accept it?

Comment: If you think my answer answered your question, then it's nice to mark it as "answered" .